# Error after upgrading to xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.1 "used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.6, ios6.1

After updating to xcode 4.6 and ios6.1, I get this new error **"'objectType' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector**". I get this multiple times. Any ideas?

PS: The method that it get displayed is a custom one for reverse geocoding.

```
-(void) getAddress: (NSString *) objectType: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) objectCoordinate
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It says that `objectType` is the name of the `NSString` object in your method and not part of the method name and it should not be used as `objectType: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) objectCoordinate` which normally denotes a part of method name.

Ideally you should change,

```
-(void) getAddress: (NSString *) objectType: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) objectCoordinate
```

to a more readable,

```
-(void) getAddress:(NSString *)objectType coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) objectCoordinate;
```

The above error can also be fixed by putting a space between `objectType` and next param in method definition(For eg:- `-(void)getAddress:(NSString *)objectType : (CLLocationCoordinate2D)objectCoordinate`). Note the space after `objectType`.

***Update:***

To answer the question in comments you can use the below line to suppress these warnings:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-selector-name"
```

Add this in your pch file. I am not sure if this will work for your case where it comes from library but you can try it out. Check [this clang-trunk](https://github.com/eerolanguage/clang-trunk/blob/master/test/SemaObjC/warning-missing-selector-name.m) for more details.

Comment: If the methods belong to you, then you can go ahead and make these changes and fix the warning. Would you have any suggestions on what to do if the warnings come from a library that you are using? Any build settings that you have come across maybe?

Comment: @Guven, Not sure whether this will work but you can try with `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-selector-name”` in your pch file. Updated my question.

Comment: Correction: _Updated my answer"_.

Comment: @ABC, you have a so called "smart quote" at the end of your pch #pragma.

Answer (score 5):

It's all about the **spacing, darling**...  as @Martin R said re: this, [debateably BETTER question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660091/xcode-4-6-used-as-the-name-of-the-previous-parameter-rather-than-as-part-of-the)...

> "It is sufficient to insert a space before the second parameter."

Sufficient meaning, here, that Xcode shuts the hell up..

In the spirit of that odd piece of syntatic trivia...  here's my favorite Cocoa header file, EVER.  and yes, those are all valid method names, hehe.

```
@interface NSString (JASillyString)
-:a;
-:a :b;
-:a :b :c;
-:a :b :c :d;
-:a :b :c :d :e;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p :q;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p :q :r;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p :q :r :s;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p :q :r :s :t;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p :q :r :s :t :u;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p :q :r :s :t :u :v;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p :q :r :s :t :u :v :w;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p :q :r :s :t :u :v :w :x;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p :q :r :s :t :u :v :w :x :y;
-:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p :q :r :s :t :u :v :w :x :y :z;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is declaring the selector With spaces,

```
-(NSString *)testMethod:(double)price :(BOOL)flag;
```

Note mention .h and .m both are same and equal spaces

When retrive methode, that time careful about method and its arguments.
like
[self testMethod:4.5(space):TRUE];