# How to disable new Xcode 4.6 warning for whole project ? “… used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.6

I know how to fix it by inserting whitespace before : , but I have it know in bunch of files after upgrade and this is not important problem for me.
I am searching for it in build settings but none seems to address this.

Thank You.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577478/error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-6-and-ios-6-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I found this for single file :

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-selector-name”
```

Name I got from here: https://github.com/eerolanguage/clang-trunk/blob/master/test/SemaObjC/warning-missing-selector-name.m

So I put it in precompiled header “Project.pch" and it works for my whole project, I am interested in nicer solution if possible, as user defined build setting for example. I tried it, but not found syntax that worked.