# Error when Declaring arguments for a method in objective C

Tags: c, methods, arguments

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, I am following a tutorial online(thenewboston) and I am getting an error that says "w used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector."

```
-(void)setWH: (int) w:(int) height;
```

Comment: Please provide complete code..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error after upgrading to xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.1 "used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577478/error-after-upgrading-to-xcode-4-6-and-ios-6-1-used-as-the-name-of-the-previous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing part of the selector name:

```
- (void)setWidth:(int)width height:(int)height;
//                          ^--- You're missing this.
```